# Pass checkbox value to laravel controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms

I need to grab the value of a checkbox by using jQuery and pass it to my Laravel controller so I can store the value in the database.

I need the values to be true or false / 1 or 0... Cannot be null.

How can I pass the checkbox value to the Database?

**Here is the checkbox:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="cats" id="cat" checked>
```

**Here is my Script that is also grabbing other values with no problem:**

```
function updateExtraFields(fieldName, selector) {
    $('form input[name="' + fieldName + '"]').val($(selector).val());
}

$('#cat').on('click', function() {
    updateExtraFields('cats', '#cat').prop('checked');
 });

$('#dog').on('change', function() {
    updateExtraFields('dogs', '#dog');
});

$('#bird').on('change', function() {
    updateExtraFields('birds', '#bird');
});

//Something else I was trying... $("#cat").attr("checked") ? 1 : 0;
```

**Controller:**

```
$xxxx->table_name()->create([
    'cats' => $request->cats === 'true',
    'dogs' => $request->dogs,
    'birds' => $request->birds,
]);
```

**UPDATE / ANSWER**
I ended up figuring out my issue. I needed to create a hidden field to pass the checkbox value to, then I could store in my DB

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cats" id="cat" checked>

<input type="hidden" value="" name="cats" id="hidden_check">
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
//Added value on page load
$('#cat').attr('value', '1')
$('#hidden_check').attr('value', '1')

 // Changed value when checked
  $('#cat').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('value', '1');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('value', '0');
  }  

//Sent value to hidden field
    var checkbox_field_value = $(this).val();
    $('#hidden_check').val(checkbox_field_value);
  });
});
```

This code is working for me, but if there is a cleaner way to write it, please let me know.

Comment: by using ajax you can send the data

Answer (score 0):

```
$xxxx->table_name()->create([
  'cats' => $request->cats == 'true' ? 'true' : 'false',
  'dogs' => $request->dogs,
  'birds' => $request->birds,
]);
```

If the `$request->cats` equals 'true', it'll take `true` to be the value for `cats`. If there's any other value it will be `false`. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to controller using Ajax. Following code demonstrates how you can do it

```
var catStatus=$('input[name="cats"]:checked');  // get the value of the checkbox

/*Now make the ajax call*/
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: '/sendcatStatus',
    datatType : 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        status: catStatus
    },
    success:function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});

/*Laravel route*/
Route::post('/sendcatStatus','ControllerName@methodName');

/*Your Contoller Method */

public function methodName(Request $request){

    dd($request->input('status'));
}
```

I have shown this for one checkbox. Similarly you can use the ajax call for sending multiple data.